# SQL, Recursive query to get ancestors with some rules of all parents

Tags: sql, mysql, recursive-cte

```
ID    parent_id          name       is_public
------------------------------------------------
1        null         category 1        0
2        1            category 2        0
3        2            category 3        0
4        3            category 4        0
5        4            category 5        1
```

I need return rows where is_public = 0 and all ancestors is_public = 0 too
In this case it should return ID: 1, 2, 3, 4

But for example if I set ID = 1 is_public = 1 it shouldn't return any row.

I have tried SQL like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursiveTree AS (
      SELECT task_categories.id, task_categories.name, task_categories.is_public
      FROM task_categories WHERE task_categories.is_public = 0

      UNION ALL
      SELECT tc.id, tc.name, tc.is_public
      FROM recursiveTree
      INNER JOIN task_categories tc ON recursiveTree.id = tc.parent_id
      WHERE tc.is_public = 0
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM recursiveTree WHERE recursiveTree.is_public = 0
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/MOpfujWT

But it still return rows where parent.is_public = 1;

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi - when I run your query using your data it doesn't return any records where parent.is_public = 1. Please can you update your question to show the result you are getting? BTW in your data you have a column called NAME and in your SQL you have a column called TYPE - I assume one of these is a typo?

Comment: @NickW I updated post and added DBFiddle.

Comment: BTW the data in your question doesn't match the data in the dbfiddle: ID = 1 is_public column, for example

Comment: Your anchor clause is going to pick all rows where is_public = 0 i.e. 2, 3, 4. It will then find all children where is_public = 0 for these rows . So your result is everything in your anchor clause + plus all their children. Which is why you get 2, 3, 4 in your result

Comment: @NickW please read description of what I need 

I need return rows where is_public = 0 and all ancestors is_public = 0 too In this case it should return ID: 1, 2, 3, 4

But for example if I set ID = 1 is_public = 1 it shouldn't return any row.

 I described two cases, but anyway logic should be:
Get all rows with is_public = 0 AND ALL ancestors should have is_public = 0 too

Comment: Your anchor clause should only pick up the top-level node in your tree (i.e. ID=1) so try changing that WHERE clause to include "and parent_id is null"